# what is reliable way of getting name of primary domain controller?

Tags: active-directory

I am using function NetGetDCName, but this seems to fail (err 2453) on a production Active directory

I used nltest.exe to test

Output of nltest /DCNAME:dir
`Status = 2453 0x995 NERR_DCNotFound`

However nltest/DCLIST:dir  seems to list all the domain controller including the PDC.

How does nltest/DCLIST work ? I guess nltest /DCNAME:dir is using NetGetDCName only and fails with same error as my code.

I also did a nslookup on the host where I am getting error. I see that the DNS that it is pointing to is not one of the domain controller host.

Any tips on how should I get the PDC programatically?

Comment: By PDC, do you mean the PDC Emulator role or, possibly, looking to figure out which DC is Global Catalog master/replica?

And which versions of Windows? 2003, 2008, 2008R2???

On the command line, you can dump the roles with:

netdom query /domain:<your NB domain name> fsmo

Comment: There is no PDC in an AD domain, it is a multi master environment. Do you want the name of the server that holds the PDC emulator role?

Comment: PDC is primary domain controller

Comment: @user52014: Yes, that is what the acronym means. In AD, however, the PDC role is merely an emulated role that any DC can perform.  It is largely for backward compatibility with NT4 domains. Please see this [technet for more details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727049.aspx#EEAA) about roles in AD.

Comment: I suppose if your AD is running on NT4, PCD may be the correct terminology.

Answer (score 3):

dsquery server -hasfsmo pdc

will return the FQDN of the domain controller who is holding the PDC Emulator role.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this tool ;-), but it works in a 2003 domain:

```
Z:\bin>nltest /dcname:domain
PDC for Domain domain is \\server
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: PDC is primary domain controller

Comment: I know, so? What I meant was that using the tool like that it works. I just masked the real domain name and server name